# Does Docker need a program to access peripherals?

Tags: docker, driver

```
Can't Open the card!
```

I wrote a driver for a peripheral. I have been able to run it in the host, but in the dokcer can not run the program. Will it need a procedure in the host to achieve reuse, like docker access to the network card needs the bridge?
     Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to mount the device you want to use in your

`docker run -v`

command

Extract from

https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/docker-containers-on-the-desktop/

for example a Spotify docker image needs access to the sound device, so

`$ docker run -it \
    -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \ # mount the X11 socket
    -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY \ # pass the display
    --device /dev/snd \ # sound
    --name spotify \
    jess/spotify`

also the Skype docker image

`$ docker run -d \
    -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime \
    -p 4713:4713 \ # expose the port
    --device /dev/snd \ # sound
    --name pulseaudio \
    jess/pulseaudio`